# How to send a buffer with spi

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, c, spi

I use an atmega32 and I want to use the SPI bus. I have the Adafruit 24 channel, 12 bit pwm led driver. I use a buffer to set the pwm for a certain channel.

The question is how to send the whole buffer via SPI?

My code:

```
/*
lat = ss
dat = mosi
clk = clock
oe = miso is not used because it is one directional
*/

uint16_t *pwmbuffer;
int numdriver = 1;

void tlc5947(uint8_t n){
    pwmbuffer = (uint16_t *)calloc(2, 24 * n);
    /* Set MOSI and SCK output, all others input */
    DDRB = (1 << dat)|(1 << clk)|(1 << lat);
    /* Enable SPI, Master, set clock rate fck/16 */
    SPCR = (1 << SPE)|(1 << MSTR)|(1 << SPR0);
}

void write(){
    /* Start transmission */
    SPDR = pwmbuffer; // Here is the problem, I don't know how to do this

    /* Wait for transmission complete */
    while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)));
}

void setPWM(uint8_t chan, uint16_t pwm){
    if (pwm > 4095){
        pwm = 4095;
    }
    if (chan > 24 * numdrivers){
        return;
    }
    pwmbuffer[chan] = pwm;
}

int main(){
    // This is not my real code but a simplified version of it
    tlc5947(numdriver);
    while(1){
        setPWM(4, 2000);
        write();
        _delay_ms(5000);
        setPWM(4, 100);
        _delay_ms(5000);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: One byte at a time.

Comment: So I need to loop over my whole buffer every time? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If the chip has DMA (I'm not sure if that one does or not) you could configure DMA to send the buffer in the background.  Again, it's one byte at a time, but the DMA engine does it instead of the CPU.

Comment: How can I do this efficiently? (never done this before)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to select the slave by asserting SlaveSelect (the 'lat' bit?), then loop, sending the buffer 8 bits at a time, by writing to SPDR and waiting for completion for each byte. Then de-assert SS and you're done. There's no more efficient way than that.

Most likely, SS will be asserted by setting it LOW.

More powerful microcontrollers (I assume you're using an 8-bit AVR?) will be able to send more than 8 bits at a time. But the AVR is limited to 8-bit transfers.

Answer (score 0):

I post this answer for who doesn't know how to do this in code.

```
// The array pwmbuffer is 16 bits wide for each element. 
uint16_t pwmbuffer[24];  // Another function is used to fill this array. This will not be handled in this section.

// I use hardware SPI off an Atmega32 chip to transmit 12 bits with 24 channels.
void write(){
    uint16_t tempbuffer;

    // Make Slave Select low to address the device.
    PORTB &= ~(1<<lat); // lat is the slave select.

    for(int i = 0; i <= 23; i+=2){
        tempbuffer = pwmbuffer[i];

        //Now to send 12 bits data, one need to send first byte.
        SPDR = (uint8_t) (tempbuffer[i] >> 8);
        // Wait until every bit has been transmitted.
        while(!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF)));

        tempbuffer = pwmbuffer[i-1];

        /* Now one need the last 4 bits of the 12 bit data. These bits are the first 4
        bits of the second 8 bits of the 16 bits. The problem is that SPI needs 8 bits
        to transmit. To solve this problem one uses the first 4 bits of the next data
        block and or it together. So one become 8 bit. Remember that the 4 bits of the
        second data block becomes last. So one get 8 + (4+4) + 8 to send, the 4 last bits of the 16 bit data block will not be used. I use a mask so that only the 4 bits needed
        will be normal, the rest of the 16 bits will become 0.*/
        SPDR = ((uint8_t) (pwmbuffer[i] & 0x00F0)) | ((uint8_t) ((pwmbuffer[i-1] >> 12) & 0x000F));
        while(!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF)));

        // Now one can send the 8 remainder bits of the 12 bit data of the second data block.
        SPDR = (uint8_t) (tempbuffer[i-1] >> 4);
        while(!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF)));
    }

    // Make Slave Select high, to de-address the device.
    PORTB |= (1<<lat);
}
```

I hope this would be usefull.